# Decreasing sequence of closed convex sets in a Banach space

Tags: gn.general-topology, banach-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $(C_n)$ be a decreasing sequence of closed convex subsets in a Banach space $(E,\Vert \cdot \Vert)$. The question I have is about the content of $C=\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty C_n$.

If the $C_n$ are compacts then $C$ is nonempty. This is also the case when the $C_n$ are closed balls, even when $E$ is of infinite dimension.

$C$ can be empty, see [An empty intersection of nested closed convex subsets in a Banach space](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/an-empty-intersection-of-nested-closed-convex-subspaces-in-a-banach-space/) even when all the $C_n$ are included in a closed ball. $C$ is not empty when $E$ is uniformly convex (and therefore when $E$ is a Hilbert space) when $d = \sup_n d(0,C_n)$ is finite.

Question: what are other "general assumptions" that force $C$ to be nonempty?

Comment: In the case of convex sets, [Helly's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem) comes to mind. There exist many extensions and related results, see [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=MuEFJR7Ek4EC&lpg=PA101&ots=vqlH32JS0K&dq=grunbaum%20helly%20type&lr&hl=de&pg=PA101#v=onepage&q=grunbaum%20helly%20type&f=false) for an old survey.

Comment: The obvious condition is to require ${\rm diam}(C_n) \to 0$. (Works if the $C_n$ are closed, not necessarily convex.)

Comment: Another obvious condition to get $C$ non empty is to assume that $E$ is reflexive and that the $C_n$ are bounded, closed and convex; or, more generally, that $E$ is a dual space and that the $C_n$ are bounded, weak$^*$ closed and convex.

Comment: In connection with the example linked to the question: One can find examples with empty intersection by looking at a bounded linear functional $f$ which does not attain its norm on the unit ball $B$ (by James' theorem such functional exist for each nonreflexive Banach space), and then consider  sets $C_n=\{x\in B:~ f(x)\ge ||f||-\frac1n\}$.